# Is it good practise to rely on the insertion order of python dicts?

Tags: python, programming-practices

Since python 3.7, it is [guaranteed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980323/are-dictionaries-ordered-in-python-3-6) that dictionaries maintain insertion order. The linked stackoverflow Q&A states

> This simply means that you can depend on it.

**Is it good practise to depend on this fact?**
On the one hand it is a language feature and can be used. On the other hand, there are probably many python developers who don't expect that a change in the order of insertions to a dictionary would change the behaviour of the program. Is there a consensus on this matter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on which "Python developers" you're talking about.

If you're talking about co-workers who will help you write and maintain the code, the reliance on dict ordering should be discussed and decided upon beforehand. Ideally, everyone should be on the same page regarding language version/features and coding style. In-code reminders such as @timgeb 's example are also good.

On the other hand, if you're discussing consumers of your library code, you only need to warn about the Python >= 3.7 dependency. IMO we're all consenting adults, and it's not your job to educate your users about the language's features.

Although from a practical point of view, I'm struggling to think of a case where consumers should even care about such a specific implementation detail. You're probably better off creating an abstraction around the dict, so that users won't even have to wonder whether they're working with dictionaries in the first place (this of course depends on your actual use case).

So to answer the question, **yes, I believe it's fine to depend on this feature**. The actual question is whether you're fine with limiting your consumers to using Python >= 3.7 or not.

Comment: Thanks for the distinction! I was generally thinking of cases where other people would end up reading my code and modifying it, possibly long after I'm gone, or maybe in an open-source repo. One option would of course be to leave a comment every time that feature is relied upon, which is probably sensible anyway where the code is complex enough that this would matter

Comment: If that's your concern, then your code base is going to need tests anyway. At that point, whether you rely on a particular language feature or not in neither here nor there, as long as the code presents the desired behavior (as verified by the tests).

Answer (score 4):

I rely on it, because I generally think new features should be used until they are well known. Until then, it would be nice to leave a comment for your colleagues such as

```
for k in my_dict:
    # NOTE: relies on deterministic 3.7+ key ordering
```

and also to enforce that the project requires Python 3.7+.

On the other hand, I can see the argument for using a `collections.OrderedDict` even if you just need the insertion-ordering because it is more explicit and clear to everybody.

Unfortunately, `OrderedDict` is in a bit of an awkward state now. Since 3.7+, regular dicts provide its most prominent feature (insertion-ordering), but you can't just port over its lesser used methods (such as `move_to_end`) to regular dicts and remove `OrderedDict` from `collections`, because `OrdereDict` also takes the insertion-order into account for equality checks.

It's also weird to me that sets in 3.7+ don't provide insertion-ordering, even though I often think of dicts as sets of keys with associated values.

Honestly as I am writing this I'm kind of talking myself out of relying on `dict` insertion-ordering ...